closed form expression for the generating function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{m+n}{n} x^n$
How to find the closed form expression for the generating function:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{m+n}{n} x^n\quad
\mbox{where}\ m\ \mbox{is a}\ positive\ integer\ ?.
$$

Welcome on MSE. Can you show your word so that we can help you?

One way is to show it by induction. If you don't know a closed formula, you can compute the ${m+1}$-st in terms of the $m$-th.

Does this answer your question? Closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k} x^n$ (Negative Binomial Theorem)

Thanks, @Kolakoski54 We can find it and proove by induction

We are gonna show that for all $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geqslant 0}$,
$$f_n(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{m+n\choose n} x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}$$
For $m=0$, ${n \choose n}=1$ and therefore
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{n\choose n}x^n =\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n =\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}$$
If the formula holds for some $m\geqslant 0$, then we're gonna show that it also holds for $m+1$. By Pascal's formula,
$${m+1+n\choose n}={m+n \choose n}+{m+n \choose n-1}$$
Therefore,
$$f_{m+1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{m+1+n\choose n}x^n =f_m(x)+ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{m+n+1\choose n}x^{n+1}=f_m(x)+xf_{m+1}(x)$$
and you get the relation
$$(1-x)f_{m+1}(x)=f_m(x)$$
and then
$$f_{m+1}=\frac{f_m(x)}{1-x}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+2}}$$
By induction the formula holds for all $m$.

You should write $(1 - x) f_{m + 1}$ rather than $f_{m + 1}(1 - x)$

Of course. I changed it. Thank you!

$$
\color{#44f}{\Large\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{m + n \choose n}x^{n}} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-m - 1 \choose n}\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n} =
\color{#44f}{\Large\left(1 - x\right)^{-m - 1}}
$$
